# Computer won't boot

Tags: boot-failure

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 over my Windows 7 OS and a couple of errors appeared, I cannot remember what they said but, I tried rebooting and now when my computer starts it first shows the first image when you first boot it but then all that appears is a blinking dash in the upper left hand corner of the screen and I have tried pressing every button and nothing happens. The only thing I can do is Con+alt+delete and have the system restart only to have the same thing happen. I was trying to install from USB. Should I try burning the OS to a disk or what can I do to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider trying a CD/DVD instead.  I have had some problems in the past with using a flash drive over a disc.

Take a look at the following posts:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=68510

and then
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1498417

I would try the recommendations there and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try and if I get any error messages I will write them down and post them.

Comment: I'm running installation again and here are the errors I get.

Comment: Ubi-partman crashed
"ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entierly or be broken."

Comment: it also tells me to upgrade the python3.2, and python3.2-minimal versions and to then check if the problem still occurs.